# Difference between combiner and partitioner

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, partitioner

I am a newbie to MapReduce and I just can't figure out the difference in the partitioner and combiner. I know both run in the intermediate step between the map and reduce tasks and both reduce the amount of data to be processed by the reduce task. Please explain the difference using an example.

Comment: Partitioners don't reduce the amount of data, they determine _which_ reducer will process a given key, ie they control where data goes after the map stage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think a little example can explain this very clearly and quickly.

Let's say you have a MapReduce Word Count job with 2 mappers and 1 reducer .

### Without Combiner.

`"hello hello there"` => **mapper1** => `(hello, 1), (hello,1), (there,1)`

`"howdy howdy again"` => **mapper2** => `(howdy, 1), (howdy,1), (again,1)`

Both outputs get to the **reducer** => `(again, 1), (hello, 2), (howdy, 2), (there, 1)`

### Using the Reducer as the Combiner

`"hello hello there"` => **mapper1** with **combiner** => `(hello, 2), (there,1)`

`"howdy howdy again"` => **mapper2** with **combiner** =>  `(howdy, 2), (again,1)`

Both outputs get to the **reducer** => `(again, 1), (hello, 2), (howdy, 2), (there, 1)`

### Conclusion

The end result is the same, but when using a combiner, the map output is reduced already. In this example you only send 2 output pairs instead of 3 pairs to the reducer. So you gain IO/disk performance. This is useful when aggregating values.

The Combiner is actually a Reducer applied to the map() outputs.

If you take a look at the very first [Apache MapReduce tutorial](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html), which happens to be exactly the mapreduce example I just illustrated, you can see they use the reducer as the combiner :

```
job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
```

Answer (score 14):

First thing, agree with **@Binary nerd** s comment

> Combiner can be viewed as mini-reducers in the map phase. They perform
>   a local-reduce on the mapper results before they are distributed
>   further. Once the Combiner functionality is executed, it is then
>   passed on to the Reducer for further work.
>
> where as `Partitioner` come into the picture when we are working on more
>   than one Reducer. So, the partitioner decide which reducer is
>   responsible for a particular key. They basically take the `Mapper`
>   Result(if `Combiner` is used then `Combiner` Result) and send it to the
>   responsible Reducer based on the key

***With Combiner and Partitioner scenario :*** 
[image]

***With Partitioner only scenario :***

[image]

Examples :

- [Combiner Example](http://www.evoketechnologies.com/blog/hadoop-combiner-mapreduce-api/)
- Partitioner Example :

  > The partitioning phase takes place after the map phase and before the
  >   reduce phase. The number of partitions is equal to the number of
  >   reducers. The data gets partitioned across the reducers according to
  >   the partitioning function . The difference between a partitioner
  >   and a combiner is that the partitioner divides the data according to
  >   the number of reducers so that all the data in a single partition gets
  >   executed by a single reducer. However, the combiner functions similar
  >   to the reducer and processes the data in each partition. The combiner
  >   is an optimization to the reducer. The default partitioning function
  >   is the hash partitioning function where the hashing is done on the
  >   key. However it might be useful to partition the data according to
  >   some other function of the key or the value. -- [Source](https://hadooptutorial.wikispaces.com/Custom+partitioner)